# Can HVCP users see all records?

Tags: customer-portal, sharing, role-hierarchy, hvcp, owd

For a custom object,

- `OWD` is private
- `View all` is unchecked

Yet, HVCP user can see other people's records for that custom object.

- Is this expected because HVCP users are not part of Role hierarchy?
- Can I hide records from HVCP which don't belong to the current user?

Comment: How is the HVCP user accessing the records - is it through the standard UI or are you using Visualforce.
If the custom object has a relationship to the account or contact for the HVCP and you have set up sharing sets, they will also be able to see the record.

Comment: @BobBuzzard, the `HVCP-license` users are accessing through standard UI of Customer Portal using Custom Object Tab. There are no relationships to Standard Objects, I am only using Custom Objects in my app. I have not set up sharing sets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

High-volume customer portal users are unable to participate in the salesforce sharing model. This means:

- The setting in *Setup | Security Controls | Sharing* have no impact on
  them.
- The role hierarchy has no impact.
- Apex managed sharing rules, and manual sharing have no impact.

What you get instead is the ability to restrict them to seeing record where either their account or contact is in any lookup field on the record. You can set this per-profile and per-profile under *Setup | Customer Portal | Settings*. For example with cases:
[image: Sharing set]

As Ralph poined out, apex running in system mode (e.g. without sharing) is exempt from the above as it bypasses the sharing model and the HVCP sharing sets completely.

There's also a great graphical summary of the features available to the various types of portal users [over at the limitexception blog](http://limitexception.herod.net/2013/01/24/object-access-by-salesforce-portal-license/). The licenses in red circles are what this answer describes.

Comment: To add on to that excellent answer, apex run without sharing will allow them to view all records (seems obvious, but portal users are no for being non-intuitive)

Comment: This is an excellent answer